# How can I connect my frontend form of my reactjs project with the backend nestjs that I use?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nestjs

I have a problem with my project where I use Reactjs as frontend and nestjs as backend. I'm not able to connect the frontend form that is in reactjs with the backend nest js. I tried but I don't know why it's not working. And I'm not able to store into the database the data I entered into the form on the frontend reactjs. I dont know if the connection URL is wrong or not. Here is my frontend form in reactjs that I named Creationdirection.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react'
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'
import Header from './Header'
import axios from 'axios';

function Creationdirection() {

    const [codedirection, setCodedirection] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);
    const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!codedirection || !description) {
          setHasError(true);
          setSuccessMessage('');
        } else {
          axios
            .post('http://localhost:3000/direction', { codedirection, description })
            .then((response) => {
             
                setHasError(false);
                setSuccessMessage('La direction a été ajoutée avec succès !');
                setCodedirection('');
                setDescription('');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
                setHasError(true);
                setSuccessMessage('');
              });
          
        }
      };

  return (
    <Fragment>

      <div x-data="setup()" >
          <div className="flex flex-col flex-auto flex-shrink-0 min-h-screen antialiased text-black bg-white dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-white">

            <Header />
            <Sidebar />

          <div className="h-full mb-10 ml-14 mt-14 md:ml-64">

          {/* Contact Form */}
              <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center mx-4 mt-8" >
              <h3 className="text-3xl font-bold dark:text-white">VEUILLEZ  REMPLIR</h3>
                 
                <div className="w-1/2 p-8 m-4 bg-white rounded shadow-2xl">

                    <h1 className="block w-full mt-4 mb-6 text-2xl font-bold text-center text-gray-800">DIRECTION</h1>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="post" action="http://localhost:3000/direction">

                    {hasError ? (
                        <div className="flex p-4 mb-4 text-sm text-red-800 border border-red-300 rounded-lg bg-red-50 dark:bg-red-500 dark:text-red-400 dark:border-red-800" role="alert">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" className="flex-shrink-0 inline w-5 h-5 mr-3" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 10a8 8 0 11-16 0 8 8 0 0116 0zm-7-4a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zM9 9a1 1 0 000 2v3a1 1 0 001 1h1a1 1 0 100-2v-3a1 1 0 00-1-1H9z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                        <span className="sr-only">Info</span>
                        <div>
                          <span className="font-medium">Danger alert!</span> Veuillez remplir tous les champs obligatoires !
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    ):null}
                    {successMessage ? (
                        <div className="flex p-4 mb-4 text-sm text-green-800 border border-green-300 rounded-lg bg-green-50 dark:bg-green-100 dark:text-green-400 dark:border-green-800" role="alert">
                        <svg aria-hidden="true" className="flex-shrink-0 inline w-5 h-5 mr-3" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 10a8 8 0 11-16 0 8 8 0 0116 0zm-7-4a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zM9 9a1 1 0 000 2v3a1 1 0 001 1h1a1 1 0 100-2v-3a1 1 0 00-1-1H9z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                        <span className="sr-only">Info</span>
                        <div>
                          <span className="font-medium">Success alert!</span> {successMessage}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    ):null}

                        
                        <div className="flex flex-col mb-4">
                            <label className="mb-2 text-lg font-bold text-gray-900" >Code de la direction</label>
                            <input className="px-3 py-2 border text-grey-800" type="text" id="code" value={codedirection} onChange={(e) => setCodedirection(e.target.value)} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex flex-col mb-4">
                            <label className="mb-2 text-lg font-bold text-gray-900" >Description</label>
                            <input className="px-3 py-2 border text-grey-800" type="text" id="description" value={description} onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}  />
                        </div>
                        
                        <button className="block p-4 mx-auto text-lg text-white uppercase bg-green-400 rounded hover:bg-green-600" type="submit">Enregitrez</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

              </div>
              {/* ./Contact Form */}


          </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.8.0/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
        
         
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default Creationdirection
```

And now just below, you will see my backend nestjs files
Let's started by the direction.entity.ts

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
@Entity()
export class Direction {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  
  @Column()
  codedirection: string;

  @Column()
  description: string;
}
```

Just after, we have my direction.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Direction } from './direction.entity';

@Injectable()
export class DirectionService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Direction)
    private directionRepository: Repository<Direction>,
  ) {}

  async create(direction: Direction): Promise<Direction> {
    return await this.directionRepository.save(direction);
  }

}
```

Now the direction.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Post, Body } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DirectionService } from './direction.service';
import { Direction } from './direction.entity';

@Controller('direction')
export class DirectionController {
  constructor(private readonly directionService: DirectionService) {}

  @Post('/direction')
  async create(@Body() direction: Direction): Promise<Direction> {
    return await this.directionService.create(direction);
  }

}
```

Now direction.controller.spec.ts

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { DirectionController } from './direction.controller';

describe('DirectionController', () => {
  let controller: DirectionController;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [DirectionController],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<DirectionController>(DirectionController);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

direction.service.spec.ts

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { DirectionService } from './direction.service';

describe('DirectionService', () => {
  let service: DirectionService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [DirectionService],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<DirectionService>(DirectionService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Now my app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Direction } from './direction/direction.entity';
import { DirectionController } from './direction/direction.controller';
import { DirectionService } from './direction/direction.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: '00000',
      database: 'revuecompte',
      entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, HeadcountController, DirectionController],
  providers: [AppService, HeadcountService, DirectionService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Please, help me, I don't know exactly how to solve it now. I tried everything for my part. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You provided good information, but you forgot the error message that you're getting. It can help debugging. anyway... I noticed this:

```js
import { Controller, Post, Body } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DirectionService } from './direction.service';
import { Direction } from './direction.entity';

@Controller('direction')
export class DirectionController {
  constructor(private readonly directionService: DirectionService) {}

  @Post('/direction')
  async create(@Body() direction: Direction): Promise<Direction> {
    return await this.directionService.create(direction);
  }

}
```

this controller will only receive post request at `http:localhost:<PORT>/direction/direction` but throw error at `http:localhost:<PORT>/direction/`

try to modify it like so:

```js
import { Controller, Post, Body } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DirectionService } from './direction.service';
import { Direction } from './direction.entity';

@Controller('direction')
export class DirectionController {
  constructor(private readonly directionService: DirectionService) {}

  @Post()
  async create(@Body() direction: Direction): Promise<Direction> {
    return await this.directionService.create(direction);
  }

}
```

Comment: I tried it but it's still not working

Comment: Have you seen the form for the frontend ?

Comment: You still forgot to provide what error you're getting